# Compose material design new version depreciation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is the code I used to set the Colour of text field in jetpack compose

After upgrading the following dependencies, I encountered a problem

> /academic_calendar/add_event/AddEventCalendarFragment.kt: (346, 9): Cannot find a parameter with this name: textColor"

So the field ( textColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,) does not exist anymore
[Problem occured while compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Kj7.png)
[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3YFY.png)

These are my all dependencies

```
val colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        textColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Unspecified,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Unspecified


    )

    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.3'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.1"
```

How can I resolve this error

I don't know what should I try. please help me by providing proper tutorial

Answer (score 2):

In Material3 the [`textFieldColors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldDefaults#textFieldColors(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.text.selection.TextSelectionColors,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)) function is deprecated.

On top of that the [`TextFieldColors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldColors) class got redefined and no longer includes a `textColor` field. You should take a look at the new structure of the `TextFieldColors`.

Those changes meant that there was a new function added - [`colors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldDefaults#colors(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.text.selection.TextSelectionColors,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)). You should use this one instead of `textFieldColors` now.

You should also replace the `textColor` field with `focusedTextColor`.

```kotlin
val colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
    focusedTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Unspecified,
    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Unspecified
)
```

You should still take a closer look at the new [`TextFieldColors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldColors) and examine new fields (like `unfocusedTextColor` for example) and decide which of them you should use for better user-experience and compliance with Material3 design guidelines.